# Django Redirect Returning 200 But Page Not changing

Tags: python, django, http, redirect

I've got a form in Django that I submit with code like the following:

```js
  XHR.open("POST", "/route/to/post/view");
  XHR.send(formData);
```

and the route for it looks something like this:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        context = {"object": Perso.objects.all()}
    
        return render(request, "myview.html", context)

    elif request.method == "POST":
        print("post request is", request.POST)
        print("redirecting...")
        return redirect("/route/to/another-view")
```

I know that this is working correctly because I get the following output printed when I press the POST button page:

```
post request is <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['6pdzvTNVO8d1KhS9w3IevFGD7w3bprBRQtUaO1TuXDS4RIkTP44IlFdYwJQB7czx'], 'vaccinator': ['tilley evan']}>
redirecting...
[12/Apr/2021 15:42:34] "POST /route/to/post/view HTTP/1.1" 302 0 
[12/Apr/2021 15:42:34] "GET /route/to/another-view HTTP/1.1" 200 3546
```

and in Chrome I can see that a successful GET request was made, but for some reason the page itself doesn't change.

Any advice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the request is redirected it is actually the XHR request, not the browser. At that point there is no request going from the browser itself, just javascript. I would suggest you have the `/route/to/post/view` return a URL (in a JSON for example) and then use `window.location` in JS to redirect the browser.

*Poorly explained, I know, I just can't quickly think of a better way to differentiate between the "browser" and the "js" parts.*